# Latency in scaling VCore( say from 2 to 4) of Elastic Pool vs Create new Pool with VCore (4) and moving the databases

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-elasticpool

We have sort of a load balancer implemented for sql elastic pools. Basically it merges two pools, or splits two pools or scales up storage based on some reference settings (compute, storage etc) and the stats we get from the sql server. In some cases, as a special case of spliting a pool into two or more pools, we create a pool with larger vcore and then move the all databases from the old pool to the new pool. The question
is there a performance hit by creating a new pool with desired vcore and move the databases to the new pool vs scaling the vCore to the designed level in place or are they both the same since scaling in place also internally creates a new tier?

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 1):

> The question is there a performance hit by creating a new pool with
> desired vcore and move the databases to the new pool vs scaling the
> vCore to the designed level in place or are they both the same since
> scaling in place also internally creates a new tier?

There is no such performance hit observed, however below are few notable points.

1. The databases in an elastic pool are **on a single server and share** a set number of resources at a set price. They ensuring that databases get the performance resources they need when they need it. They provide a simple resource allocation mechanism within a predictable budget.
2. When moving databases into or out of an elastic pool, there is no downtime except for a brief period of time (on the order of seconds) at the end of the operation when database connections are dropped.

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-scale) official MS doc to understand the factors affected while changing service tier or rescaling.